# The use of mod operators in ada

Tags: ada

Can anyone please tell me the usage of the following declarations shown below.I am a beginner in ada language.I had tried the internet but that was not clear enough.

```
            type Unsigned_4 is mod 2 ** 4;
            for Unsigned_4'Size use 4;
```

Answer (score 3):

`Unsigned_4` is a "modular type" taking the values 0, 1, .. 14, 15, and wrapping round.

```
   U : Unsigned_4;
begin
   U := Unsigned_4'Last;      -- 15
   U := U + 1;                -- 0
```

You only need 4 bits to implement the type, so it's OK to specify that as its Size (I think this may be simply a confirming spec, since the compiler clearly knows that already; if you were hoping to fit it into 3 bits and said `for Unsigned_4'Size use 3;` the compiler would tell you that you were wrong).

Most compilers will want to store values of the type in at least a byte, for efficient access. The minimum size comes into its own when you use the type in a packed record (pragma Pack).

Answer (score 1):

The "is mod" is Ada's way of saying that this is a [modular type](http://www.ida.liu.se/edu/ugrad/progkon/Ada/ada-doc/LRM95/rm95html/rm9x-03-05-04.html). Modular types work a bit like `unsigned` types in C: They don't have negative values, and once you reach the largest representable value, if you add one you will get 0.

If you were to try the same with a normal (non-modular) integer in Ada, you'd get `constraint_error`